How to type a function parameter as a property of a generic type?
I have a function that receives two parameters, an object type T, and a string which must be a property of the object T, where the value must be a boolean. I want to be able to specify this in TypeScript:
function doThing<T>(object: T, propertyOfT: HowToTypeThis<keyof T, boolean>) {}

I've gotten this far:
function doThing<T>(object: T, propertyOfT: keyof T) {
  object[propertyOfT] = true // propertyOfT is indeed property of T, but you don't know if the value is boolean
}

I have gotten it much further, but I had to use assertion which defeats the purpose in my opinion:
type BooleanKey<T> = { 
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends boolean ? K : never 
}[keyof T];

function doThing<T>(object: T, propertyOfT: BooleanKey<T>) {
  object[propertyOfT] = true as T[BooleanKey<T>]; // <= does not work without assertion
}


This question is similar to: Get property field names of type. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is two issues: lack of native TS support for BooleanKey, see ms/TS#48992; & the lack of native TS support for allowing writes of boolean to the prop, see ms/TS#14520. You can deal with the former by making it generic in propertyOfT instead of object like this, but the latter is just a hole in the language (see this). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

This is what I came up with, try
function doThing<T>(object: Record<keyof T, boolean>, propertyOfT: keyof T) {
  object[propertyOfT] = true // propertyOfT is indeed property of T, but you don't know if the value is boolean
}

